# nodejs 340 error: cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed node.js on a windows 7 ultimate machine.

Created a hello world program with one line
console.log('hello world');
saved it into the same folder as installation.
went to that folder in command prompt
and tried to execute the file using
node hello.js
It is giving error

`c:\Program Files\nodejs>node hello.js`

`module.js:340

    throw err;`

        ^

I have read all the answers for same question asked ,none of them worked for me.

how can I solve this issue?

Comment: does node console works fine?

Comment: full error description is given below

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Program Files\nodejs\hello.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3

Comment: node console works fine

Comment: sometimes files saved inside installation paths don't have right permissions. is it your case?

Comment: I have tried with executing it outside the installation folder also.Inthat case also it gives the same error.